# ChangeSelectedValue of a Select event

Tags: javascript

How may I fire an event when I change the selected value of a the tag `<select>` using `JavaScript` ?

I tried something like this, but I'm lost now ;s I want to change the value of a label when I change the selected value of the `<select>` tag.

```
function ChangeSelectValue(ddlID, value, change) {
     var ddl = document.getElementById(ddlID); 
}
```

Comment: How are you calling this method

Comment: What? What method? D:  
Also I tried `<Select onChange="NameofTheFunction(...)">` didnt work out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simple ,Just return the selected value from select option using onchange=display(this.value) where dispaly() is user defined function and this.value returns the selected value

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <script>
            function display(str) {
                alert(str);
            }
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>

        <h1>My First JavaScript</h1>
        <p id="demo">This is a paragraph.</p>

         <select id="Country" onchange="display(this.value)">
         <option id="I" value="India">India</option>
          <option id="P" value="Pakistan" >Pakistan</option>
          <option id="S" value="SriLanka">SriLanka</option>
            <option id="C" value="China" >China</option>
          </select>

        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: it's working with FireFox. why it is not working with GoogleChrome ?

Comment: please modify the code as shown below ,so that it may work in                                  
        <select id="Country" onchange="display(this.value)"><option id="I" value="India">India</option>
        <option id="P" value="Pakistan" >Pakistan</option>
        <option id="S" value="SriLanka">SriLanka</option>
        <option id="C" value="China" >China</option>
        </select>

Answer (score 0):

At its simplest this requires very little JavaScript:

```
var selectEl = document.getElementById('fruits');
function labelChange () {
    var label = document.querySelector('label[for="' + this.id + '"]');
    label.textContent = 'You chose: ' + this.value;
}

selectEl.addEventListener('change', labelChange);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wX3z4/).

Though the above code is designed for contemporary/modern browsers that implement `addEventListener()` and `document.querySelector()` methods.

For more backwards-compatibility, the following also works, though it's a little 'clunkier' than I'd like:

```
var selectEl = document.getElementById('fruits');
function labelChange () {
    var labels = document.getElementsByTagName('label'),
        text = 'textContent' in document ? 'textContent' : 'innerText',
        label;
    for (var i = 0, len = labels.length; i<len; i++) {
        if (labels[i].htmlFor == this.id) {
            label = labels[i];
        }
    }
    label[text] = 'You chose: ' + this.value;
}

selectEl.onchange = labelChange;
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wX3z4/1/).